# Good algorithms for feature extraction from images?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-selection

I am searching for some algorithms for feature extraction from images which I want to classify using machine learning . I have heard only about [scale-invariant feature transform][1] (SIFT), I have images of buildings and flowers to classify . Other than SIFT what are some good algorithms .

Comment: it would be preferable if someone could also provide links to those algorithms (sort of tutorials) which they are describing .

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of feature selection techniques for computer vision, but I think one of the more promising recent developments is a Deep Belief Net (DBN) strategy.

Geoffrey Hinton has used layers of unsupervised networks (Restricted Bolzmann Machines) to extract the optimal features from images in a training set. He then uses the trained RBM's as input into a ANN for classification.

[Here](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/) is a site that gives some thorough tutorials on DBN's and related topics.

I hope this helps.